# trap in freestyle shell script not working in jenkins

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jenkins, kill

I want the **gracefull** killing of my Jenkins job if someone aborts it,
So I tried to trap the abort signal and customise killing step using shell script.

But It seems like Jenkins is ignoring all the trap and killing forcefully anyway 

sample script to test

```
exit_script() {
    echo "Printing something special!"
    echo "traped &  killed " >>text.txt
    echo "Maybe executing other commands!"
    trap - INT TERM ABRT  QUIT HUP # clear the trap
    kill -- -$$ # Sends SIGTERM to child/sub processes
}

trap 'exit_script' INT KILL ABRT QUIT HUP

echo "pid is $$"
echo "pid is $$" > test.txt
count=0
sleep 10
echo 1
echo 1 >>test.txt
sleep 10
echo 2
echo 2 >>test.txt
sleep 10
echo 3
echo 3 >>test.txt
sleep 10
echo 4
echo 4 >>test.txt
sleep 10
echo 5
echo 5 >>test.txt
sleep 10
echo 6
echo 6 >>test.txt
exit 0
```

I am looking for how we can trap **SIGTERM** signal and customise kill command in jenkins.

FYI:
This script work fine in my system bash, just need to change INT->SIGINT and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is working fine,
just for needed few corrections, If there is any issue with function associated with trap i.e `exit_script()` it won't work.

I tested it by removing `kill -- -$$` and it works fine the function is being called and the process continues to execute.

Answer (score 0):

In general, in a shell script, you trap the SIGTERM signal by saying

```
trap 'exit_script' TERM
```

P.S. Trapping KILL doesn't work, and listing QUIT twice doesn't help.

Comment: It works in Bash shell locally but I am having trouble in trapping the abort operation in Jenkins